Нахождение максимального произведения элемента массива и расстояния между элементами
Дан массив целых чисел. Необходимо найти пару элементов так, чтобы произведение минимального из них на расстояние между элементами (разница индексов) было максимальным для всего массива.
Необходимо вернуть произведение минимального элемента пары на расстояние между элементами.
Например, [2, 5, 2, 2, 1, 5, 2] -> 20,   (5 * (5-1)) - взята пара 5 и 5;
[1, 2] -> 1
Не эффективное решение:
a = [2,5,2,2,1,5,2]
res = -10**9
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    for j in range(i+1,len(a)):
        res = max(res, min(a[i],a[j])*(j-i))

print(res)

Код не проходит по времени. Как сделать его более эффективным?

Вложенные циклы не проходят по времени

В идеале тут бы квадратичный алогритм заменить на что-то более быстрое, но пока ничего не придумывается.

Что тут думать,  просто пары элементов значение+индекс отсортировать и потом один проход от больших значений к меньшим и все. Сложность будет линейно-логарифмической.

Нашелся линейный алгоритм.

Набросал решение на C#. Суть в том, чтобы массив превратить в пары (значение + индекс), отсортировать по значению и пробежать от больших значений к меньшим.
var data = new[]{2, 5, 2, 2, 1, 5, 2};
var sorted = data.Select((x,i)=>(x,i)).OrderBy(x=>x).ToArray();

int min = sorted.Length-1;
int max = sorted.Length-1;  

int ret = 0;

for(int i=sorted.Length-2; i>=0; i--) {

    var test1 = sorted[i].x * Math.Abs(sorted[i].i - sorted[min].i);
    var test2 = sorted[i].x * Math.Abs(sorted[i].i - sorted[max].i);
    
    if (test1 > ret) ret = test1;
    if (test2 > ret) ret = test2;
    
    if (sorted[i].i < sorted[min].i) min = i;
    if (sorted[i].i > sorted[max].i) max = i;       
}

Console.WriteLine(ret);

Вывод в консоль: 20, получилось из за двух 5 с индексами 1 и 5, то есть 5 * (5-1) = 20.
Сложность линейно-логарифмическая из за сортировки. Если числа все небольшие, то можно и в линию уложиться.

Не пишите, пожалуйста, условие if и его тело в одной строке, это конечно короче, но выглядит не очень понятно )

@CrazyElf это дело привычки. Мне, например, так удобней писать и читать код, хотя видел команды где обязывают каждому if ставить фигурные скобки.

Ну да, скобки нужны, чтобы не было сюрпризов, когда ты допишешь что-нибудь, а оно не попадёт в if. С фигурными скобками как-то очевиднее куда и что попадёт )

Это справедливо если пишешь много кода, то есть на работе (там на java пишу) я так и делаю. А тут просто небольшой кусочек кода на пару строк, потому тут я себе позволяю такие вольности =) Мне, если честно, просто нравится в одну строку делать if, если строка умещается в экран. Но я с вашими доводами согласен.

Площадь прямоугольника – произведение расстояния от левой до правой границы прямоугольника на минимум их высоты.
Пусть ai и aj - кандидаты в левые границы максимального по площади прямоугольника. Если i < j и ai ≥ aj, то прямоугольник с левой границей i всегда будет по площади больше прямоугольника с левой границей j.
Другими словами нет смысла проверять левые границы, которые ниже левых границ, встреченных ранее (двигаемся слева направо). Из массива a надо выбрать возрастающую подпоследовательность левых границ.
По той же причине для правых границ тоже следует выбрать возрастающую подпоследовательность значений. Только теперь мы двигаемся справа налево.
Высота максимального прямоугольника всегда равна его левой или правой границе. Для каждой левой границы в возрастающей последовательности правых отыщем, первую, которая большее или равна левой. Это и будет самый большой прямоугольник для фиксированной левой стороны.
Аналогично строится максимальный прямоугольник для фиксированной правой стороны. Когда рассмотрены все максимальные прямоугольники для всех правых и левых сторон, среди них был глобально максимальный. Задача решена, причем было просмотрено линейное количество прямоугольников.
Решение со сближающимися левой и правой границами заимствовано из ответа Leonid и немного доработано. Двигается та граница, забор на которой ниже. Если высоты заборов равны, двигать можно любую границу. candidates выдаёт последовательность площадей прямоугольников, среди которых гарантированно есть максимум.
def candidates(a):
    yield 0                            # for len(a) == 1
    i = 0
    j = len(a) - 1
    hi = a[i]                          # = max(a[:i + 1])
    hj = a[j]                          # = max(a[j:])
    while i < j:
        yield min(hi, hj) * (j - i)
        if hi < hj:
            i += 1
            hi = max(hi, a[i])         # = max(a[:i + 1])
        else:
            j -= 1
            hj = max(hj, a[j])         # = max(a[j:])


print(max(candidates(tuple(map(int, input().split())))))

Память – линейная (O(N)). Время тоже O(N). Сортировки нет, вместо неё отбор возрастающих подпоследовательностей для левых и правых заборов.
